# windows *.bat file user input and validation

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i wrote basic script that can check user input. if user not filled script must ask about name input again. But something is went wrong, we're i missed?

```
   @echo OFF
    title Enter your name
    color 0a

    set /p Name="Your name: " %=%

    :start

    if "%Name%"=="" (goto try)

    :try
    cls 
    color 0a
    echo You must enter your name!
    color 0c
    set /p Name="Your name: " %=%
    if "%Name%"!="" (goto init) else (goto try)

    :init
    color 0a
    cls
    Echo %Name% is saved...
    reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\example" /v "YourName" /t REG_SZ /d "%Name%"  /f
    Pause&Exit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if "%Name%"!="" ...
```

is not a valid syntax. Instead use:

```
if not "%Name%"=="" ...
```

or

```
if "%Name%" neq "" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed code and now it works!

```
@echo OFF
title Name pl0x
color 0a
:start
set /p Name="Your name: " %=%


if "%Name%"=="" (

cls 
color 0a
echo You must enter your name!
color 0c
goto :start
) else (
color 0a
cls
Echo %Name% saved...
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\example" /v "YourName" /t REG_SZ /d "%Name%"  /f
Pause&Exit
)
```

Comment: Now the thing to do is accept Stephan's answer since he pointed out your original error.